# Conditional Rolling Mean

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hello I have the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()
df.index = ['2009-01-04', '2009-01-05', '2009-01-05', '2009-01-06', '2009-01-06', '2009-01-07', '2009-01-07', '2009-01-07']
df['score1'] = [84, 28, 38, 48, 23, 38, 22, 37]
df['score2'] = [83, 43, 12, 93, 64, 28, 29, 12]
df['score3'] = [92, 33, 11, 48, 23, 22, 12, 38]
df['score4'] = [43, 23, 41, 75, 93, 93, 23, 21]
df['condition1'] = [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]
df['condition2'] = [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
df['condition3'] = [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1]

df = df.resample('D', how='mean')
df = df.rolling(30, min_periods=1).mean()
```

I'd like to do a rolling mean over 30 days, but with an over-weight on the rows having one of the "conditions" met (ie. condition==1). ie. the rows meeting the conditions will greatly impact the 30-day timeframe.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: What is your "over-weight"?

Comment: for example, over a 30-day timeframe, I'd start by assigning 30% for the row having the controversy. Then it would decrease by 1% every day

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I understand but couldn't you use a weighted score based on the condition to do the rolling over ?

```
extra_weight=2 # when condition is met, score is multiplied by extra_weight+1 

df['weighted_score1']=df['score1']*(df['condition1']*extra_weight+1) # we add 1 so that score is counted even when condition == 0
#repeat for score2 and 3
df = df.rolling(30, min_periods=1).mean()
```

Update to answer the comment : Apply weight based on multiple conditions.

In your conditions columns, you have only 1 and 0.
To satisfy an AND condition between 2 columns, you can take the min. Indeed, if both columns are 1, you get 1 and if one or both columns are 0, you get 0.
Similarly, to satisfy an OR condition, you can take the max.

So for example, if you want to add an extra weight for `(condition1 AND condition2) OR condition3`:

```
import numpy as np
df['final_cond']= np.maximum(np.minimum(df['condition1'],df['condition2']),df['condition3'])

df['weighted_score1']=df['score1']*(df['final_cond']*extra_weight+1)
```

Comment: i like the idea but it's not only for condition1... It could be condition1 AND/OR condition2 AND/OR condition3. How would you adjust this?

Comment: Do you mean only one condition can impact a row?  So, if condition1 and condition2 are both 1 in a row, only a single weight will be applied?